# Chrome extension tab.url undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm using a chrome extension with a button in the popup.html that opens a new tab. The destination URL of the new tab holds the URL of the current (original) tab as a parameter.

For instance: when fired from `http://stackoverflow.com/`, the new tab should have an URL like `http://www.mydestination.com/index.php?url=http://stackoverflow.com/`

Here's my js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (tab) { 

    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://www.mydestination.com/index.php?url=' + tab.url});
    }); 

})
```

The new tab is opened perfectly, but the URL is `http://www.mydestination.com/index.php?url=undefined` (url = undefined).

I reckon the manifest.json holds the right permissions:

```
{      
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "My project",
"version" : "1.7",
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon" : "img/icon.png",
  "default_title" : "My project",
  "default_popup": "html/main.html" 
},
"permissions": [
  "tabs"
],
"icons": {
  "16": "img/icon.png"
}
}
```

Any clues on how to get the url transported properly?

Comment: whoa wait, "tab" would actually be the click event, dont you mean `addEventListener("click", function(evt, tab) {...` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that current tab is your chrome popup. In this case you don't have valid URL.
You have to select your tab. To do this you can use [chrome.tabs.query](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query). Select current window with active tab:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function () {
        chrome.tabs.query({
            'active': true,
            'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT
        }, function (tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.create({
                url: 'http://www.mydestination.com/index.php?url=' + tabs[0].url
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are passing `tab` as a parameter when it has nothing to do with the events. While some `chrome.*` apis do include a tab object as a parameter, you can't just add it on like that and expect it to have the info you want. You could do something like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { 
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow:true},function(tab){
      // Just doing it like this to make it fit on the page
      var newUrl = "http://www.mydestination.com/index.php?url=" + tab[0].url;
      chrome.tabs.create({url:newUrl});
    });
  }); 
});
```