# Why does tab.url from the callback of "chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener()" return undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For my Chrome extension, I need to show the `pageAction` only on a certain website. I used to do this with `declarativeContent`, but it isn't supported on Firefox, so I have to do it the manual way. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244748/how-do-i-make-page-action-appear-for-specific-pages) suggested that you could simply use something like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status === "complete" && tab.url) {
    if (tab.url.match(/google.com/)) {
      chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    }
  }
});
```

This didn't work for me, so I modified the code in the background script to look like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  console.log("Tab updated! Tab URL: " + tab.url);
});
```

Every time you update a tab the console just prints `Tab updated! Tab URL: undefined` a few times. I also tried to query the tab like the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511260/chrome-extension-tab-url-undefined) said, which produces the same output.

The other files of the extension are:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Test for StackOverflow",

  "permissions": ["activeTab"],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    This is a popup!
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `tabs` permission from your manifest.json file. With this permission the URL of the tab should also be logged to the console.

```json
"permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs"] // <-- This
```

manifest.json:

```json
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Test for StackOverflow",

  "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs"],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```